# python script gives different output in compute node and head node

Tags: python, unix, bioinformatics, hpc, sungridengine

I wrote a python wrapper script that calls algorithms from command line. The name of the algorithm that is called it [vcftools.](http://vcftools.sourceforge.net/man_latest.html)

In vcftools, with the current command line, It should create log file and result file.

When I run my python script in head node of the HPC, it works just fine. But when I send to queuing system in order to run in the cluster, it creates a an error;

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './final/PRAD-US/DO36253/final.9e272bea-9193-4c10-a802-f7e18b2937a3.snv_mnv_dkfz.log'
```

But when I run this in headnode, like I said before no error was generated. But it creates the result file as it was expected. So only log file is missing.

To not distract the thread i only share the line that calls vcf tools.

```
vcf_isolation_bash_script=["/mnt/kufs/scratch/tmorova15/softwares/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools","--gzvcf", output_directory+ 'annotated_full.' + analysis_id+'.snv_mnv_'+analysis_method, "--bed" ,  bed_file_input , "--recode" ,"--recode-INFO-all", "--out", output_directory + "final." + analysis_id + ".snv_mnv_" + analysis_method ]
r1=subprocess.check_call(' '.join(vcf_isolation_bash_script),shell=True)
```

What could be the reason of this problem? To be more clear about my terminology, headnode means I run my script straight through terminal, whereas in compute node, I use a queuing file which I have to specify everything (python path etc..)

Thank you for your help,

Best,
Tunc.

Edit: To be clearer,

`output_directory = './final/%s/%s/' % (folder_prefix[folder][1],folder_prefix[folder][0])`

The general structure is as follows

```
Top directory
-final/
--final.patientid.resultfile
--final.patientid.log 
-input/
--Contains all the input files
```

Edit 2: Updates

Pathing in the script is correct.

-We ran the script in headnode and gave the output as expected

-We ran the script with qsub file ( to send to compute nodes ) we end up having the current issue, but if we login those compute nodes and run the script with the same export lines, code itself work as expected.

We have Sun Grid Queuing system in our system so I think it is related with the filesystem.

Comment: Might be an obvious question, but do you ensure the target directory exists before trying to write to it? You are using a relative path (`"./final/..."`) meaning its dependent on the current working directory. Batch jobs usually run in a temporary working directory. You may wish to check `os.getcwd()` both on the head node and worker node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer MisterMiyagi. I state my top directory at the start of the script such as; `topdirectory='/mnt/kufs/scratch/tmorova15/vcf_analysis`, plus, when I run the code which produces log and result files, it writes result file but not log file.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but do you actually `cd`/`os.chdir ` there? A subprocess will inherit the current working directory unless you change it. `subprocess` allows you to set the `cwd` of processes, and python itself can change the cwd via `os.chdir`.

Comment: Being %100 sceptic will solve this issue so no problem, in order to avoid that problem. I created a scturecture such as; there is a head folder which contains input and final folders. All the raw data is in input and all the processed data is written to final one. I change no cd/os.dir or etc. I state that top folder once than all the outputs are written relative to that.

I have a question, if there was a problem in my paths, wouldn't this effect the result file as well ? Because it was written without any problem ?

Comment: Judging from the error you posted, `output_directory`  is actually `./`, i.e. the current directory. This isn't the same as `topdirectory` unless you chdir there or *already start in it*. When testing my own batch scripts, I usually already start in the desired directory. Such an error would thus not occur in the interactive session, since `./` is correct. On a worker node, `./` is some randomly selected work directory. Long story short: it *might* happen. Just check that your *absolute* paths are correct on both head and worker node.

Comment: Ah... I see your point.. 
This is my output directory variable. In the code I accidentally put the same name to my final directory and final result. I will check if that causes problem, but like I said, the result file came out successfully without encountering the you have mentioned .

Thank you 
`output_directory = './final/%s/%s/' % (folder_prefix[folder][1],folder_prefix[folder][0])`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have some updates. We tried the command in headnode and in the compute nodes. It worked succesfully in both of the nodes. But when we use a queuing system, somehow, log file is not created for a reason.